# Heroku large size problem for deploying rasa

Tags: api, heroku, web-deployment, chatbot, rasa

I have an issue when I'm trying to deploy my Docker image of RASA in heroku.

here is the  screenshot:

[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoqE5.png)

How I can avoid this large size:

I used `requirement.txt` to install RASA, here is the screen shot:

[requirements.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cx3EL.png)

Can you help me please?

Comment: Please replace screenshots with text. Screenshots are not helpful to anyone reading it.

Comment: It reads as if you're deploying on an instance that is too small.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to increase the Dyno size (this is not free).
Alternatively you can build a small Docker image, for example not using the Tensorflow or Spacy model (which are pretty large).
You typically need those if you want, for example, to use their NER models (extracts names, locations, etc..)

This is an example on how to build a Rasa instance which can fit in the free-tier:

```
   # from rasa base image
   FROM rasa/rasa:1.8.0
   # copy Rasa config and the Rasa generated model
   COPY . /app


   # script to run rasa core
   COPY startup.sh /app/scripts/startup.sh
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
But I see that you are using rasa/rasa:1.8.0 which have 613.85 MB ( more than 500M : a free-tier on Heroku).
Can you please help?

Comment: Hello Yassine, my suggestion is to build a Docker image locally and push it to the Heroku Docker registry. Docker images are not subject to size restrictions unlike slugs, which instead is what you are using (pushing the code via GIT heroku).

Build/tag the image then push it: `heroku container:release web -a myapp`